# Docker - IP address of container on Windows

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, scylla

The task is follows:
Write node.js server that will work with a ScyllaDB, that will be placed on Docker container.
I doing this earlier, but on Ubuntu, and its work fine, now I should do it on Windows 10.

I installed Docker Toolbox for Windows and run commands from the scylladb docs.

```
$ docker run --name some-scylla -d scylladb/scylla
af51fa65627303db16a3de85003be8a165a64f37cf6ae29c0b4e887d64342ad2\

$ docker exec -it some-scylla cqlsh
Connected to  at 172.17.0.2:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE nodeTask WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};
```

After this on my Node.js server I can set connection:

```
const cassandra = require("cassandra-driver")
const client = new cassandra.Client({
 contactPoints: ["127.0.0.1"],
  localDataCenter: "datacenter1",
  keyspace: "nodetask"
})
```

As I say its works fine on Ubuntu with this IP - 127.0.0.1, BeaverDB(GUI) connect to this IP with 9042 port as default, but on Windows its doesn't work. There is no possibility to work on Ubuntu now.

Sorry for the bad question and maybe a little information, but I'm new to this and simply don’t know what exactly I need to tell

Comment: Is the Node.js server supposed to live in a Docker container as well?

Comment: Yes, should be in Docker container

Comment: configure Scylla to use listen address 127.0.0.1  
docker run --name some-scylla -d scylladb/scylla --listen-address 127.0.0.1

Comment: I already tried to do it, it doesnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, so your Node.js container keeps pinging itself instead of the host (your laptop). You can create your own bridge network and attach the two containers to that bridge network

```
docker network create scylla-net
```

Now run the ScyllaDB container as follows

```
docker run --name some-scylla -d --net=scylla-net scylladb/scylla
```

In your Node.js script, change the `127.0.0.1` to `some-scylla` (name of your ScyllaDB container). The cool thing about user-defined bridge networks is that they let your containers talk to each other via their names. So the name `some-scylla` would resolve to whatever IP address the `some-scylla` container is using at the time.

Now when you run your Node.js server, be sure to pass the  `--net=scylla-net` flag otherwise it wouldn't be able to resolve the name `some-scylla`. Hope this helps!

Comment: But it doesnt help me if i want, for example, start DBeaver from Windows and connect to scylla

Comment: If you want to expose scylla to connections outside the bridge network you can expose the container ports by doing `docker run -p <HOST PORT>:<CONTAINER PORT> --name some-scylla -d --net=scylla-net scylladb/scylla`